# ANTLR help - can't parse a normal text but all the other more complex rules work

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar

I have a grammar that is very simple - it parses a bunch of text that was entered by the user for various keywords, and then does string replacements for those keywords while leaving all the other text "as is".

Basically, this grammar should do nothing to most of the text... it should just echo that text... except for when it runs into `${...}`, `$video{...}`, `$image{...}` and `$audio{...}`

My grammar mostly works now, but it can't parse normal text like `hey` using the **chunk** rule, but for some reason, it parses `<p>hey</p>` using the **chunk** rule. Why? How can I get both to use the **chunk** rule?

Basically, I want **CHUNK** to catch everything else that is not being picked up by the other rules.

I refactored the grammar a bit to make everything more clear. It would seem that **everythingElse** is getting confused with **label**? I don't know though, but `hey` does not work :(

```
grammar Text;

@header {
}

@members {
    int numberOfVideos = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public String getResult() {
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

text
    :   expression*
    ;

expression
    :   fillInTheBlank 
        {
            builder.append($fillInTheBlank.value);
        }
    |   image 
        {
            builder.append($image.value);
        }
    |   video
        {
            builder.append($video.value);
        }
    |   audio
        {
            builder.append($audio.value);
        }
    |   anchor
        {
            builder.append($anchor.value);
        }
    |   everythingElse
        {
            builder.append($everythingElse.value);
        }
    ;

fillInTheBlank returns [String value]
    :   '${' LABEL '}' 
        {
            $value = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"" +
                $LABEL.text +
                "\" name=\"" + 
                $LABEL.text +
                "\" class=\"FillInTheBlankAnswer\" />";
        }
    ;

image returns [String value]
    :   '$image{' URL '}'
        {
            $value = "<img src=\"" + $URL.text + "\" />";
        }
    ;

video returns [String value]
    :   '$video{' URL '}'
        {
            numberOfVideos++;

            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.append("<div id=\"video1\">Loading the player ...</div>\r\n");
            b.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n");
            b.append("\tjwplayer(\"video" + numberOfVideos + "\").setup({\r\n");
            b.append("\t\tflashplayer: \"/trainingdividend/js/jwplayer/player.swf\", file: \"");
            b.append($URL.text);
            b.append("\"\r\n\t});\r\n");
            b.append("</script>\r\n");

            $value = b.toString();
        }
    ;

audio returns [String value]
    :   '$audio{' URL '}'
        {
            $value = $URL.text;
        }
    ;   

anchor returns [String value]
    :   URL
        {
            $value = "<a href=\"" + $URL.text + "\">" + $URL.text + "</a>";
        }
    ;   

everythingElse returns [String value]
    :   CHUNK
        {
            $value = $CHUNK.text;
        }
    ;

LABEL
    :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*
    ;
URL
    :   'http://' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'.'|'/'|'-'|'_'|'%'|'&'|'?')+
    ;
CHUNK
    //: (~('${'|'$video{'|'$image{'|'$audio{'))+
    :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|' '|','|'.'|'?'|'\''|':'|'\t'|'\n'|'\r'|'\"'|'>'|'<'|'/'|'_'|'='|';'|'('|')'|'&')+
    ;
```

I am new to antlr - been using it for about a day, so please don't expect me to know a lot about it specifically.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "| URL" case before "| CHUNK"?

Comment: Could not reproduce that - ANTLRworks debugger shows the parse tree root -> text -> expression -> http://www.example.com/

Comment: @polkageist: Yes, it seems I fixed the URL problem... but I figured out that the problem is more general than just URLs (my bad... I didn't realize it until now). Now basic text like `hey` does not work with this grammar, but `<p>hey</p>` works.

Comment: @egervari: Yes, that's because LITERAL is a special case of CHUNK. You also need to add a rule for LITERAL.

Comment: @polkagiest: Hrm... isn't ANTLR smart enough to know that LITERAL (I renamed it to LABEL now, sorry about that) is only used between `${...}` ? Shouldn't it always assume it's a CHUNK when it's not inside a `${...}`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If I remove LABEL from the grammar, `hey` will work. How can I fix this? I don't want to use CHUNK for both random text and the labels. I could understand why there would be a problem if I said, "CHUNK | LABEL", but shouldn't it be smart enough to know that LABEL is only used when it's inside the `fillInTHeBlank` rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm choosing this way to respond because of space restrictions and lack of formatting possibilities. So, anyway:

Nope. CHUNK and LABEL are Lexer (Scanner) rules, whereas fillInTheBlank is a parser rule. The parser operates *on top* of the scanner, that is, the scanner does not know about the parser (rules). You have to introduce *lexer states*:

First, you have to introduce an additional lexer member keeping the state, telling you whether you want to read a label or not:

```
@lexer::members {
    private boolean readLabel = false;
}
```

Then, you have to introduce explicit token definitions for '${' and '}' (I'm calling them BEGIN_VAR and END_VAR) which modify this state variable. Furthermore, END_VAR tokens can only be created when readLabel is true:

```
BEGIN_VAR
    : '${' { readLabel = true; };

END_VAR : { readLabel }?=> '}' { readLabel = false; };
```

You also have to tell the lexer that LABEL tokens, too, are to be generated only in this state:

```
LABEL
    :   { readLabel }?=> ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*
    ;
```

Note that it's crucial here that this definition appears *before* CHUNK.

Finally, you have to modify your fillInTheBlanks rule using the above token definitions:

```
fillInTheBlank returns [String value]
    :   BEGIN_VAR LABEL END_VAR 
        { ...
```

Hope this helps, seems to work for me.

Comment: Wow, I will give this a try. This is certainly using more advanced features than I even knew what was there. It is weird because I've done a very similar grammar using the scala parser combinators, and I don't think I had to do any of this sort of thing. It just worked. It's interesting to see how much more powerful yet complex antlr must be. I will give this a try.

Comment: Is there any way I can parse $, { and } in CHUNK too, using a similar technique as above? Or are those characters "off limits"?

Comment: @polkageist, in case you want to answer @egervari's question (about tokeninzing `$`. `{` and `}` as `CHUNK`'s), he posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059922/how-can-i-parse-a-special-character-differently-in-two-production-rules-using-an) already. Nice answer, btw!

Comment: @BartKiers: Thanks for both the notification and the compliment ;)